# How does GetMessage() function work with hooks without a loop?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to the Win32 API. I am writing a C++ code which installs keyboard and mouse hooks, and to keep running code I am using a message loop.

To my understanding, `GetMessage()` gets the message from the message queue and dispatches it for further processing, but in the below code even if I am not using the `while` loop, just storing the value of `GetMessage()`, my code still keeps running and I am getting mouse and keyboard codes.

My doubt is if I am not using the `while` loop, `GetMessage()` should get the first message from the message queue and then it should `cout` and unhook both hooks and exit the code normally, but the code is not behaving like this.

This is the code which I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

HHOOK keyboardHook;
HHOOK mouseHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)) {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pKeyStruct = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
        DWORD keyCode = pKeyStruct->vkCode;
        std::cout << "Key Pressed: " << keyCode << std::endl;

        if (keyCode == VK_ESCAPE) {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = reinterpret_cast<MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
        int x = pMouseStruct->pt.x;
        int y = pMouseStruct->pt.y;
        std::cout << "Mouse Move: x=" << x << ", y=" << y << std::endl;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
    mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseProc, NULL, 0);

    MSG msg;
    // while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    //     TranslateMessage(&msg);
    //     DispatchMessage(&msg);
    // }
    int a = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
    cout<<a;
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(mouseHook);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you never receive any messages then `GetMessage` will block forever and doesn't need to be in a loop

Comment: [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983) Key takeaway: `GetMessage` can dispatch messages without ever returning.

Comment: How does it even possible? Can you explain in brief

Comment: @JemishVirani `GetMessage()` blocks until there is an application-level message worth returning to the caller.  In the meantime, it dispatches internal system messages without returning to the caller.  The OS can use the message queue for its own purposes, and hooks are one of several features that internally use private system messages.

Comment: The meaningful distinction here is between queued ("posted") and non-queued ("sent") messages. `GetMessage` will only ever return queued messages to the caller. For low-level input hooks the system sends messages, so they are never returned to the caller of `GetMessage`. Instead, `GetMessage` dispatches inbound cross-thread sent messages internally.

Comment: You didn't call CreateWindow() to create your own window.  So GetMessage() never has anything to return.  And blocks, otherwise keeping the hooks alive.  The primary need of GetMessage here is to tell the OS that your app is idle, so the OS can safely make the callbacks without risking re-entrancy problems.

Comment: One doesn't need a window for a thread to receive thread messages. A prominent example is [`WM_QUIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-quit).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the community:

Refer to the Blog: [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983)

> Everybody who has messed with window messaging knows that GetMessage
> and PeekMessage retrieve queued messages, which are dispatched to
> windows via DispatchMessage. Most people also know that GetMessage and
> PeekMessage will also dispatch nonqueued messages. (All pending
> nonqueued messages are dispatched, then the first queued message is
> returned.) But apparently not many people realize that SendMessage
> will also dispatch messages!